# Lightroom preview before and after last adjustment applied

Tags: lightroom, keyboard-shortcuts

When I was using only Camera Raw within Photoshop CS6 there was a hotkey available (Ctrl+Z) which allowed to cycle between current version of the settings and the previous one. It was a quick and easy way to preview the effect of the last adjustment. I used it a lot. Now when I've switched to Lightroom there is a hotkey (\) for comparing the photo with the point when it was unedited (which is not what I'm looking for) and there are also 3 other options:

- clicking between two last history states back and forth,
- copying the settings of the "now" to the "before",
- press Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Y back and forth

but none of these options is as quick and easy as the old one, so my question is: is there an easy way to mimic the Ctrl+Z hotkey from Camera Raw?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for, doesn’t exists within Lightroom.

I hope I am wrong as I also looked for it when I moved from ACR.

Lightroom within the develop module records a separate history state for each and every step and preserves these history steps (unlimited number) within a database even after you quit Lightroom.
These are then available to the user via the history panel and are selected by scrolling the cursor up and down to revert back to any stage of the development.

Adobe Camera Raw does not have an equivalent database to store such steps only the previous step can be viewed.

Therefore, taking this into account, I can only presume that it made sense for the Developers at Adobe to have a toggle hotkey feature in ACR because you will only ever go back one step and it made sense to create a history panel in Lightroom to provide the advantage of scrolling and choosing the exact history stage.

However, saying that, I would like Adobe to enable the up/down arrow keys to go up and down on the panel as that will be easier to navigate the panel.